# Openldap ppolicy, how to unlock account?

Tags: linux, password, openldap

I have enabled OpenLDAP password policy overlay and account lockout is now working fine. On 5 authentication failures the account is getting locked out. On resetting the password the account becomes open again. Any way to unlock it other than resetting the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `pwdLockoutDuration` attribute to some amount; the value is in seconds. I think that by default it is 0 (infinite).

Unlock the account manually without need for resetting the password by removing the operational attribute `pwdAccountLockedTime`.

Comment: and if I want to unlock it immediatly ?

Comment: Added that, too.